# How do you create (or set) a tracking branch? LibGit2Sharp 0.26.2

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I need to add a branch that tracks a remote using libGit2Sharp v0.26.2.  Every example I've seen uses the seemingly deprecated repo.CreateBranch() API though I'm not certain that matters.

Branches are created in 0.26.2 by using repo.Branches.Add().

I've attempted the following but I'm clearly missing something (assumes "repo" has been created and initialized and instance repo is created):

```
repo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", path_to_remote);
var trackingBranch = repo.Branches["origin/myBranch"];
repo.Branches.Add("myBranch", trackingBranch.Tip);
var branch = Commands.Checkout(repo, repo.Branches["myBranch"]);
repo.Branches.Update(branch, b => b.TrackedBranch = trackingBranch.CanonicalName);
Commands.Pull(...);
```

This code will alway fail as "origin/myBranch" does not exist in repo.Branches even though "myBranch" exists on the remote.  More interestingly, if I use the git command like and (once the code adds the remote) and do a "git pull" things work fine.

FYI: This code is cobbled together from looking at numerous examples that use deprecated calls.  I've been unable to locate anything using the current version.  Hopefully someone out there has experience with the current version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`myBranch` might exist on the remote repository, but in the code you posted, you never actually "fetch" the branches from the remote repository. Just adding the remote is not sufficient (this just configures the remote repository, but does not actually retrieve any information from it) - you also need to fetch the latest branches from the remote repository. After you fetch, your local Git repository will know about the branches on the remote, and then you can create a local branch from it.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  Would you use the actual Commands.Fetch to accomplish this or is this done with a different command.  Sorry if I'm being obtuse here.

Comment: The fetch command seems reasonable. There are examples here: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-fetch